# Horizontal scroll divs inside vertical scroll div

Tags: html, css, cordova

is it possible to scroll the outer div only vertically and the inner divs (containing smaller divs) only horizontally?
I'm using cordova for a mobile app and I can scroll the outer div both horizontally and vertically. The inner divs don't scroll.

[image]

This is the CSS for the outer div (#container), the inner divs (#line1, etc.) and the other divs inside.

```
#container {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

#line1, #line2, #line3 {
    display: table;
    width: 50em;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.smallDivs {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -6%;
}
```

The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="line1">
        <div class="smallerDivs"><div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"><div>
    </div>
    <div id="line2">
        <div class="smallerDivs"><div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"><div>
    </div>
    <div id="line3">
        <div class="smallerDivs"><div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"><div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or show us the html code?

Comment: Have you tried setting `overflow-x: hidden` on the outer div ?. Also, which are the parents of your lines?

Comment: The only parents are the ".app" div and the body. If I set overflow-x: hidden on the outer div I can't scroll anything horizontally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `white-space: nowrap;` in yours `#lineX` and set `overflow: hidden;` to `html` and `body`

Try to use this basic example to guide you:

```css
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container {
   height: 100%;
   overflow-y: auto;
   background: red;
}

#line1, #line2, #line3 {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 20px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 30px;
}

.smallerDivs {
    height: 112px;
    width: 112px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="line1">
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="line2">
         <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="line3">
         <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
        <div class="smallerDivs"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here a jsfddle to play width](http://jsfiddle.net/8dtrktpw/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use on each div an `overflow` in your css. `Overflow-y` and `Overflow-x`

For example the outer div would have `Overflow-y:scroll;`
and your inner divs will have `Overflow-x:scroll;`